# How I can Assign web roles automatically to the existing user/contact using form/flow in power pages/apps?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I'm trying to assign the web role to the existing contact by making a form/list in the power pages but I haven't found the existing power app flow to do so automatically. Please anyone can assist me in how I can assign by selecting the web role in the form against the existing contact/user????

Thanks in advance